# Web API routing in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am attempting to publish our web api to IIS 7.5. I have it deployed as an application "api". I am able to successfully deploy the application and it runs. **I can access it at /api/api/**. I believe this was due to having "api" in the routing config of the api controllers as well as having it hosted in the "api" application in IIS. I have removed the "api" portion of the route path in web api and it works correctly if I launch it from visual studio. **I would like to access it from /api instead of /api/api but IIS doesn't recognize this change**. What could be causing this in IIS? I am fairly new to IIS and I have googled around but I have not found anything useful.

TL;DR
I updated routes in my web api application but IIS is not recognizing those changes.How can I force IIS to update?

Comment: I believe you can reset your server just stoping and restarting the IIS service. But (it´s not clear to me your question), you may also set the "default page" of your POOL/website the startpage in API/API.  Anyway, maybe you need something called URL-Redirector, since it allows you to transform big URL´s in something more friendly. IIS accepts URL-Redirector.

Comment: I have restarted the IIS service already as well as the website with no luck. My question is this: How do I force IIS to host my api at <my server>.com/api and not at <my server>.com/api/api? I do not want the second api in the context path.

Comment: When you upload your project, make the upload to <server> only - do not append "/api" after. Since your project is named "api", the upload will occurr at that folder. I prefer always to publish my projects using FTP from VS. But, anyway, you may also utilize URL-Redir to make browser display "<server>/api" instead "<server>/api/api".

Comment: I am building the project on the server. I host the application by pointing the physical directory of the api application to the deployment package generated by VS. Would it make a difference to deploy directly to IIS rather than to a deployment package and then IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with this for some time I found that the problem was that I pointing the physical directory of IIS to the deployment package from VS and because I was building the project directly on the machine. This caused VS to quietly fail when it couldn't update the files because they were locked by IIS. After deploying to a new path and then replacing the contents of the application the new routing works as expected.

Comment: So, I believe my suggestion was right, isn´t it?  :)

Comment: No, I still host it exactly as I was before under /api. The problem was the files were not being updated as I thought they were.

Comment: I got it. Anyway, I´m happy you had solved the problem.